# Default bada applications

Tags: replace, default, bada

Is there any way to stop default bada applications functionality in order to make another application serve the user in the same way?

for example if I make a messaging app and wanna to make it default messaging app instead of bada ones what should I do?

I think at least I need a way to stop parallel notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in Bada 2.0 :(
If you know any way to do it - please share the info here.

Comment: Unfortunately I am agree with you and I found no way yet.